# Using C++, test existence of static member using SFINAE, return wrong value

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I am learning template metaprogramming.
When trying to test static member using following code, the second SFINAE always return wrong value:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

// ts_a
struct ts_a
{
    static int a;
};

// ts_b
struct ts_b
{
    static int b;
};

// has_a
template<typename T, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct has_a : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct has_a<T, std::void_t<decltype( T::a )>> : std::true_type {};

// has_b
template<typename T, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct has_b : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct has_b<T, std::void_t<decltype( T::b )>> : std::true_type {};

int main()
{
    printf( "%s\n", has_a<ts_a>::value ? "true" : "false" );
    printf( "%s\n", has_b<ts_a>::value ? "true" : "false" );
    printf( "%s\n", has_a<ts_b>::value ? "true" : "false" );
    printf( "%s\n", has_b<ts_b>::value ? "true" : "false" );  

    return 0;
}
```

I am using Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.15.26732.1 for x64

```
true
true
false
false
```

However when compile with GCC, it returns the expected value

```
true
false
false
true
```

When define has_b before has_a ( CTRL-XV has_b before has_a ), MSVC returns

```
false
false
true
true
```

So, is it a compiler problem?

The following alternative works on both compilers, but it also return true to non-static member. Is there a way I can detect real static member ?

```
template <class T>                                                  
struct has_a_2
{                                           
    template<typename U>                        
    static std::true_type check( decltype( U::a )* );
    template<typename U>
    static std::false_type check(...);                          

public:                                                             
    static constexpr const bool value = decltype( check<T>( 0 ) )::value;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a MSVC bug.

A bug report titled: [**Expression SFINAE problem**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/199199/expression-sfinae-problem.html) was filed for it.

As per the solution mentioned in the report, this issue is fixed and it's available in latest preview Visual Studio 2019.

This works correctly on both GCC and Clang.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, guess I have to improve my googling skill